# Automorphism class group of $R$-Alg

Tags: ct.category-theory

The automorphism class group of a category $C$ is the group of equivalences $C \cong C$ modulo isomorphism. For example, if $R$ is a ring, every automorphism of $R$ yields an self-equivalence of $R$-Alg; you just pull back the structure morphism $R \to A$ with $R \cong R$. Here I assume everything to be commutative.

If $R$ is an integral domain, then it is known that the automorphism class group of $R$-Alg is isomorphic to $\text{Aut}(R)$ ([CB]; see also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55931/invariance-of-zx-under-a-self-equivalence-of-the-category-of-commutative-ring) MO question). What is the automorphism class group when $R$ is arbitrary? The authors of the article mention that this problem is more difficult, sketch a proof when $R$ is reduced and conjecture that also in general the automorphism class group is just $\text{Aut}(R)$. Intuitively, this *should* be true. What is the current state of this problem?

[CB] : W. E. Clark, G. M. Bergman, The Automorphism Class Group of the Category of Rings, J. Algebra 24 (1973), pp. 80 - 99