# Categorical proof subgroups of free groups are free?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, free-groups, abelian-groups

> This is a crossport of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099950/categorical-proof-that-subgroups-of-free-groups-are-free) from MSE.

Is there a categorical proof that subgroups of free groups are free?
How about the result that subgroups of free *abelian* groups are free abelian?

What is it about $\mathsf{Grp}$ and $\mathsf{Ab}$ that makes subobjects of free objects free? Can one characterize such categories? In particular, are there any other ones apart from $\mathsf{Grp}$ and $\mathsf{Ab}$?

---

I have received some comments on MSE, one claiming such a proof exists, one doubting it, and another claiming it cannot be proved in $ZF$.

Comment: There was some discussion of this in some posts at the n-category cafe, IIRC, but I don't have the links to hand

Comment: Another example of such a category is that of Lie Algebras.

Comment: See here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Nielsen-Schreier+theorem, where a topological proof and a groupoidal proof are given. It might help to read them in tandem. My impression is that you need some choice to do the proof, but I don't take that as ruling out a categorical proof.

Comment: We also had a long accompanying discussion of this nLab entry at the nForum: http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/4364/nielsenschreier-theorem/

Comment: I have a sort of categorical proof that I never published.  It uses that a group G is determined up to Isomorphism by its category of G-sets and it uses left Kan extension or tensor products.  Also it verifies the universal mapping property. But at a certain moment you do need a Schreier transversal which uses choice. I can probably dig up the draft if someone wants it. I'd say that it makes categorical the part which can be but at some point a spanning tree or transversal is needed.

Comment: The idea is similar to the one we give in http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.0027 but tensor products of G-sets replace wreath products.

Comment: What's the meaning of 'categorical proof'?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.3833 is a version of my somewhat categorical proof with the language stripped out.  I had it written with a more categorical language earlier on but removed usage of functors and explicit reference to a group being determined by its category of actions.

Comment: Prospects for a categorical proof seem poor in that subgroups of free groups are not *canonically* free. I think freeness is in some sense a red herring and one should look for some other group-theoretic property equivalent to freeness but which makes no reference to a choice of free generators. Maybe cohomological dimension $1$?

Comment: As I believe I said in math.SE, I don't think you can have a true "categorical proof" (though you can probably have proofs cast in the language of categories, or proofs that have a categorical flavor), because the fact is not true "categorically". If you look at the category of all groups in a variety of groups (which is a reflective subcategory of **Groups** and hence generally speaking well-behaved), the only varieties in which "subgroup of free is free" holds are the variety of all groups, all abelian groups, and all abelian groups of exponent $p$ (a prime). (cont)

Comment: (continued) One would expect a truly "categorical proof" to be something you could do in the context of any variety of groups; but since the conclusion does not hold in most of them, I don't expect you would be able to find such a proof in the first place.

Comment: (My comment was not in the linked question, but it is in [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26985/alternative-functorial-proof-of-nielsen-schreier) ).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Subobjects of free algebras are free" is satisfied comparatively rarely for algebraic theories. I'm going to start a list and people should feel free to add. I'm making it CW.

Before starting, let me say that IMHO a more interesting general question to consider is: when are retracts of free objects free? That can be a very tough question. We had some discussion here: [Is a retract of a free object free?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90734/is-a-retract-of-a-free-object-free)

- Ben Webster got the ball rolling with various categories of modules (although he concentrated more on whether subobjects of projectives are projective). By the way, vector bundles can be seen as projective objects over the ring of smooth functions, but need not be free: some vector bundles are not trivial bundles.
- Submonoids of free monoids need not be free. This fails for even the simplest cases, e.g., the monoid generated by $2, 3$ in $(\mathbb{N}, +)$ isn't free.
- Subalgebras of free commutative $k$-algebras (aka polynomial algebras) need not be free. The subalgebra generated by $t^2, t^3$ in $k[t]$ ($k$ a field) can't be a polynomial algebra as it isn't even a UFD.
- Subalgebras of free Boolean algebras need not be free. For example, a finitely generated free Boolean algebra on $n$ elements has cardinality $2^{2^n}$, isomorphic to a power set of $P([2^n])$. A quotient of the set $2^n$, say one with 3 elements, induces an inclusion $P([3]) \to P([2^n])$ of Boolean algebras.
- Pablo mentioned that subalgabras of free Lie algebras *are* free. (What's a good reference for that?)

Comment: "some vector bundles are not trivial bundles." ho ho ho - this made me laugh. A bit like saying there are some finite simple groups that are nonabelian...

Comment: It's not even true that subobjects of relatively free groups are relatively free groups (in the corresponding variety). In fact the only Schreier varieties of groups are the variety of all groups, all abelian groups, and of all abelian groups of exponent $p$ ($p$ a prime).

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes, I know. But it's nevertheless a good example for those who haven't thought much about projective modules.

Comment: That subalgebras of free Lie algebras over a field are free was proved by Shirshov and Witt independently, in Shirshov, Podalgebry svobodnykh lievykh algebr (Russian: Subalgebras of free Lie algebras), Mat. Sbornik N.S. 33(75) (1953), 441–452, and Witt, Die Unterringe der freien Lieschen Ringe (German: Subrings of free Lie rings), Math. Z. 64 (1956), 195–216. The same result was proved for free restricted Lie algebras in characteristic $p$ by Bryant-Kovács-Stöhr in Subalgebras of free restricted Lie algebras, Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 72 (2005), no. 1, 147–156 (repairing earlier proofs).

Comment: It's not free in the categorical sense, but for the free $K$-fields $K(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, discussing whether its $K$-subfields are free amounts to the question whether unirational implies rational. For instance for $K=\mathbf{C}$, the answer is yes for small $n$ (at least $n\ge 2$) but not for large $n$.

Comment: In the topological group category, a subgroup of a free topological group need not be a free topological group (though there is a positive answer when the subgroup is assumed to be open).

Comment: @DavidRoberts Your remark reminds me of an anecdote about the movie, "It's My Turn", starring Jill Clayburgh as a math professor (famous in math circles for her proof of the snake lemma). At one point in the movie her father introduces her as someone who works in the area of finite simple groups. But apparently that scene had to be edited. The father had first introduced his daughter as someone working in the area of finite, simple, *abelian* groups. A mathematician present during the screening broke out in laughter on hearing this. Source: http://world.std.com/~reinhold/mathmovies.html#Gagola

Comment: @Todd: Oh, so a number theorist!

Answer (score 12):

Let me elaborate on my comment. I think freeness is a red herring. The content of the standard topological proof is that a covering space of a $1$-dimensional CW complex is again a $1$-dimensional CW complex. Of course this naturally generalizes to the case where $1$ is replaced by any positive integer $k$, which suggests the following definition.

Say that a group $G$ has homotopy dimension at most $k$ if $BG$ can be presented by a $k$-dimensional CW complex (e.g. take $BG$ to be a compact hyperbolic $k$-manifold). Then the same argument about covering spaces shows that every subgroup of a group with homotopy dimension at most $k$ again has homotopy dimension at most $k$. Homotopy dimension at most $1$ is equivalent to freeness in the presence of choice, but using it instead of freeness in the argument removes the need to choose a spanning tree and that should address concerns about uses of choice.

As the long list of examples in Todd's answer also suggests, we should be looking at some property other than freeness in general. I think some kind of cohomological dimension is a better candidate; as stated in Matthias Wendt's comment below, the nontrivial free groups are precisely the groups of cohomological dimension $1$. And $1$-dimensionality also shows up in Ben Webster's answer.

Comment: A reference for the last sentence: Groups of cohomological dimension one are free is a theorem of Stallings (finitely generated) and Swan (general). I support the preference of cohomological dimension over freeness.

Comment: The same is true of free Lie algebras: they are those of global dimension 1.

Comment: I like this answer.  A small comment on notation.  Your choice of $F_k$ is unfortunate, since $F_k$ is usually used for the similar property of 'having a BG with finite $k$-skeleton'.  So $F_1 =$ fg, $F_2 =$ fp etc.

Comment: @HJRW: thanks for the warning. I picked that notation because I half-remembered that similar property, but it seems I remembered it wrong. I'll pick something else.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: No, the same is not true for Lie algebras. See a paper by Mikhalev, Umirbaev, Zolotykh (DOI:10.1070/RM1994v049n01ABEH002199) where a non-free Lie algebra of cohomological dimension 1 is constructed (in characteristic p). As far as I know, in charactersitic zero this is an open question.

Answer (score 9):

Free isn't a very good notion categorically, since it requires reference to an underlying set.  A similar but catgeorically better notion is "projective." An abelian category in which all subobjects of projective modules are projective is called *hereditary*.  Abelian groups are one such example, but so are representations of a quiver, or coherent sheaves on a smooth 1-dimensional affine variety (coherent sheaves on a 1-d smooth projective variety are morally similar, but don't have many projective objects.  They have the similar property that a subobject of a locally free object is locally free).  This property follows whenever $\operatorname{Ext}^2(M,N)$ vanishes for any objects in the category (you may also need enough projectives, as well.  This is where coherent sheaves on a projective variety runs into trouble).  This theory doesn't apply to free groups, since groups aren't an abelian category.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what exactly is meant by a categorical proof but here is my best approximation.

If $G$ is a group let $BG$ be the category of right $G$-sets.  It is well known that $G\cong H$ if and only if $BG$ and $BH$ are equivalent categories.

Now if $F_X$ is a free group on $X$ then $BF_X$ is the category whose objects are sets $Y$ together with an $X$-tuple  of permutations of $Y$ where we have permutations act on the right.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $F_X$.  Choose a Schreier transversal $T$ for $F_X/H$ (this is the non -categorical part). Let $B$ be the set of nonidentity elements of $H$ of the form $txu^{-1}$ with $t\in T$, $x\in X$ and $u\in T$ the representative of $Htx$.

One needs to show that $BH$ is equivalent to the category of sets with a $B$-tuple of permutations. Given an $H$-set $Y$ you get an obvious $B$-tuple by forgetting the action of the other elements of $H$.  To go other way recall that there is a functor $BH\to BF_X$ given by $Y\mapsto Y\otimes_H F_X$. Moreover, using the transversal $T$ it is easy to see that the action of elements of $X$ on this tensor product are determined precisely by the action of $B$ on $Y$.  Thus if you have a $B$-tuple of permutations of $Y$ you can define  an $X$-tuple of permutations of $Y\times F_X/H$ and hence an action of $F_X$ on $Y\times F_X/H$ which restricts on $Y\times \{H\}$ to an action of $H$ extending the original action of $B$. This proves $H$ is free on $B$.  Schreier transversals are needed to recover the original action.

A nuts and bolts version of this argument without categorical language can be found in http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.3833